# crawling then insert into database

Tags: php, yii, simple-html-dom

i am new to yii framework and i have this code in yii and i try to insert into data base but nothing save to db why?

```
    public function actionAhmad() {
    $connection = yii::app()->db;
    $UserModel = new User();
    $AdverModel = new Adver();
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $links = array();
    $html = file_get_html('http://jo.opensooq.com/category/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%88-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%83%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AA/70');

    foreach ($html->find('tr[class="one_post"] td[class="os_new_ads_list_title"] p a')as $a) {
        //echo  $a->href;echo "<br/>";
        $links[] = $a->href;
    }

    foreach ($links as $anchor) {

        $html2 = file_get_html('http://jo.opensooq.com/' . $anchor);

        $one = $html2->find('div[class="os_new_ad_box_lft_details_box"] a');

        $UserModel->name=$one;

        if ($UserModel->save()) {

           echo 'sucsess';                
       } else {

            print_r($UserModel->getErrors());
            echo "<br/>";

       }

    }
}
```

i have this output

```
    Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name cannot be blank. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => ID cannot be blank. ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Name is invalid. ) )
```

Comment: did you get any errors from this error object $UserModel->getErrors()

Comment: `find('...', $index)` returns an array if `$index` is not specified, which is your case... The index is zero based, so 0 will gets you teh 1st element and so on...

Comment: This is not a output . its a validation errors from yii . your model did't get saved while its been cleared . or disable your validation on your appropriate model

Comment: i disable the validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your validation rules in User model . you are try to send irrelevant data into DB. Try to change your table id as auto increment and remove the rules on your User model

its look like

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('id,username, password', 'required'),  // remove id on this 
        array('password_repeat', 'required', 'on'=>'register'),
        array('password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password_repeat', 'on'=>'register'),
    );
}
```

if the rules have required validator yii through validation error if you dont want validate any fields just remove fields on this list

**Edited**
Use this for save it turn off your validation rules while save

```
$model->save(false);
```

Comment: I do it but nothing happen

Comment: $model->save(false); use this

Comment: im sorry mr.Rayan but now i have this error"Array to string conversion"

Comment: try to print this  $one variable for checking own